# GNU Screen and Finch Not Playing Nicely

Tags: command-line, instant-messaging, gnu-screen, pidgin, finch

I use [finch](http://developer.pidgin.im/) for instant messaging, and for persistence, finch is one of the things that runs in my [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session.  There are three main computers that I access my screen session from, and each works at a different screen resolution.

Because of the different resolutions, when I switch computers, I use screen -rd to attach to my screen session.  Using screen -x results in problems.  When I attach to the session, though, finch experiences display problems.  I have to wait up to several minutes for finch to become responsive - it doesn't redraw properly at all.  Trying to switch between chats just writes ^n and ^p, or ^(1-9) for numbers.  It fixes itself after some time.  Using ctrl-l does not help.  Switching back and forth between screen windows does not help.

This is an annoying behavior that I don't experience with any other applications running in screen.  Is this a bug in screen or finch, and if not, what can I change about my configuration to correct it ?

(would appreciate it if "finch" could be used as a tag for this instead of or in addition to "pidgin")

Comment: seldom-used tags are occasionally culled; if there aren't other questions with the [finch] tag after a few months it may be removed.  tags are for grouping questions together, so if finch is the console version of pidgin, it's probably best to keep the [pidgin] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current best guess: finch doesn't handle long IM conversations particularly well.  My finch instance runs on an always-on server, and I almost never close conversation windows, because I like context.  However, when I needed to reboot the server and start finch anew, the problem went away.  It came back when conversation windows got longer - and then I closed them and it went away again.  So, it's a flaw with finch, but I can change my usage patterns to adapt.

Comment: I close conversation windows almost daily but I have similar problems as well. There seems to be a filed bug of this: http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/12714

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten resigned to finch kind of sucking - it seems distinctly a second-class citizen of the libpurple programs. I notice that the bug is 20 months old, no action.